# Make iframe reponsive with jQuery, all for Mobile devices

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, mobile, iframe

From within my SharePoint environment I have to use a Page Viewer to load a custom HTML form into an iframe.  Everything works find except for the fact that the layout is set to a forced width.  Meaning the left and right sides of the screen a pretty much open.  I'm pretty good with CSS and even overriding selectors, but I have not researched on how to make iframes and its children, responsive in layout design.  How can we make it happen from scratch with jquery?

I pretty much want the width of my iframe to be as wide as its parent container and the ability to scroll longer content too. I know its more than just a 100% width.  Plus will this work for mobile devices - which is my end goal.

any small examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the browser's width:

```
$(window).width();
```

To get the window's height:

```
$(window).height();
```

To set the width of your iframe's width and height (assuming there is only one):

```
$('iframe').height($(window).height());
$('iframe').width($(window).width());
```